# Why is my SQL query for a single value failing?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following code that fails at the **if (!rdr.Read())**, and I can't see what I am doing wrong. When I look in the database using the value in `fullPath`, the record exists. Here's my code:

```
        Song song = new Song();
        connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionManager.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string query = $"SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE FullPath LIKE '@FullPath%'";
                using (SqlCommand queryString = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    queryString.Parameters.Add("@FullPath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300).Value = fullPath;
                    SqlDataReader rdr = queryString.ExecuteReader();
                    if (!rdr.Read())
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("No records were returned.");
                    }
                    song.Title = rdr["Title"].ToString();
                    song.Artist = rdr["Artist"].ToString();
                    song.Genre = rdr["Genre"].ToString();
                    song.Album = rdr["Album"].ToString();
                    song.Year = (uint)rdr["Year"];
                    song.Length = rdr["Length"].ToString();
                    song.FullPath = rdr["FullPath"].ToString();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.log.Error($"Error getting song: {fullPath}\n", ex);
        }
        return song;
```

Comment: By "fails" do you mean that no records are returned so your explicit exception is thrown?  When this happens, what is the value of `fullPath`?  What record are you expecting it to match?

Comment: Side note: you should put `rdr` in a `using`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@FullPath` placeholder for the parameter is not included in the SQL string correctly. When you use parameters, you do not put them in single-quotes. You want this:

```cs
string query = "SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE FullPath LIKE @FullPath + '%'";
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```cs
string query = "SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE FullPath LIKE @FullPath";
// ...
queryString.Parameters.Add("@FullPath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300).Value = fullPath + "%";
```

Remember, parameterized queries are more than a simple sanitization + string substitution. Rather, it *quarantines* the data inside a variable. Therefore the SQL code must treat the placeholder as an SQL variable. What you had was just a string literal where the value happened to match the parameter name.

That's as far as I got. There may be other errors, too. If you want better help, *post the actual error message*.

Comment: Quarantine isn't quite the right word, I guess it's a simplification. The `@variable` is a "placeholder", and the data is "bound" to the placeholder *after* the parsing stage, so there is simply no way for the data to ever be interpreted as anything other than a data value.

Comment: I agree. But it's better to think "quarantine" than "sanitize", which is even more incorrect but more commonly believed.